# Cloning two-dimensional Arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, clone

I know that similar questions have been asked, but after reading their answers, I keep being unable to solbe my problem: I need to implement the Java method clone, which copies all the double entries in a given two-dimensional array a to a newly created two-dimensional array of the same type and size. This method takes the array a as input and returns the new array with the copied values.

IMPORTANT: I am not  not allowed to use a library method to clone the array.

Here's what I've done so far: Maybe I didn't understand the requirements but it didn't work:

```
class Solution {
    static double[][] clone(double[][] a) {
        double[][] b = new double[a.length][a.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            b[i][i] = a[i][i];
        }
        return b;
    }
}
```

This is the error message I get:

```
Status: Done
cloneLonger(weblab.UTest) failed: 'java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<3> but was:<2>'
Test score: 2/3
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't work"? Do you get any error? Hint: you'll probably need two loops, one inside the other.

Comment: `new double[a.length][a.length]` this is not right. Your solution only considers 1 dimension of `a` for both the sizes of the dimensions of `b` and the copying of the items

Comment: @TimCastelijns yes, i was thinking that that could be the problem how should I do it instead?

Comment: @sp00m edited, my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should iterate this array with two loops. This will helps you:

```
static double[][] clone(double[][] a) {
    double[][] b = new double[a.length][];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        b[i]= new double[a[i].length];
        for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++)
            b[i][j] = a[i][j];
    }
    return b;
}
```

Comment: this will only work if `a` is a square grid, which is not a given. Also it will crash if `a` is empty

Comment: true, @TimCastelijns , what would be the most appropiate approach then?

Comment: @TimCastelijns yes I corrected my answer. Is it ok now?

Comment: @PabloBiedma I think my updated answer is correct bro

Comment: Yes @Spara I think it solved the task and I marked it as correct please upvote my question ahhaha

Comment: @PabloBiedma good question! upvoted

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work (with library method):

```
public class Util{

  // clone two dimensional array
  public static boolean[][] twoDimensionalArrayClone(boolean[][] a) {
    boolean[][] b = new boolean[a.length][];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      b[i] = a[i].clone();
    }
    return b;
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe that in my question it says that I am not not allowed to use a library method to clone the array.

Comment: The `clone` method belongs to `Object; no problem there.

Answer (score 1):

In this, your code has few mistakes. These corrections were done below. The two-dimension array has 2 lengths. In this case, you didn't consider inside array length.

```
class Solution {
    static double[][] clone(double[][] a) {
        double[][] b = new double[a[0].length][a.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
               b[i][j] = a[i][j];
            }
        }
        return b;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some logical mistakes:

 1. Matrix could be sized `M` x `N` where `M` is the number of rows and `N` is the number of columns. In your solution you are taking for granted that `M` is always equal to `N`.

 2. You are iterating trough all the rows and there you do set only one column per row like `target[K][K] = source[K][K]` -> this will go copy the diagonal only and not the whole matrix.

Comment: Okay, I understand it, how should I do it then, in order to copy the whoe matrix and in case m and n are different?

Comment: As other answers pointed out: to retrieve `M` -> `source.length`; to retrieve `N` -> `source[0].length; // Returns the length of first item from the source array.`; Use two `for` cycles -> one which goes 0 trough M (`i`) and another one nested, going trough 0 to N (`j`). Set `target[i][j] = source[i][j]` at each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Copy to a temp single row array and then assign it to the out array

```
static double[][] clone(double[][] a) {
    double[][] b = new double[a.length][];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        double[] temp = new double[a[i].length];
        for (int j = 0; j < temp.length; j++) {
            temp[j] = a[i][j];
        }
        b[i] = temp;
    }
    return b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ever more "advanced" alternatives are:

```
static double[][] clone(double[][] a) {
    double[][] b = new double[a.length][];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        b[i] = new double[a[i].length];
        //for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; ++j) {
        //    b[i][j] = a[i][
        //}
        System.arraycopy(a[i], 0, b[i], a[i].length);
    }
    return b;
}
```

Now there is a utility class `Arrays` worth knowing:

```
static double[][] clone(double[][] a) {
    double[][] b = new double[a.length][];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        b[i] = Arrays.copyOf(a[i], 0, [a[i].length]);
    }
    return b;
}
```

And for primitive arrays the `clone` method still may be used. Cloning is not very pure, bypassing constructors, and might be dropped from java in some future.

```
static double[][] clone(double[][] a) {
    double[][] b = new double[a.length][];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        b[i] = a[i].clone();
    }
    return b;
}
```

Comment: Just hammer it, this is not a new question

Answer (score -1):

You can't create new array like that. If you are sure that length and width of array is same than only this will work.

```
class Solution {
    static double[][] clone(double[][] a) {
        boolean[][] b = new boolean[a.length][];
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            b[i] = new double[a[i].length];
            for (int j = 0; i < a[i].length; j++) {
                  b[i][j] = a[i][j];
            }
        }
        return b;
    }
}
```